# Google playstore being ignored android minSDKVersion?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have set the `defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4` in build.graddle.
And I have submitted the app to playstore. In playstore console it shows API levels 19+

But still people can download the app in to devices running os version 4.3. This causes issue, because my app does not work properly on 4.3 and lower versions.

Does anyone has face this problem?

App is build using ionic

Comment: i think specifying uses-sdk may work

Comment: Use minSdkVersion 19 in default config. It is not possible to download app having minimum sdk to 19 and getting installed on android 4.3.

Comment: I have already set minSdkVersion=19 in config. But strange thing is some user could installed the app on 4.3. User has provided the screenshot as well. Is it possible the custom os can bypass and install the app?